# Calling a JS function inside another function when they are done

Tags: javascript

I need some help here with this code:

```
$.get(function1()).done(function (){ 
    $.get(function2()).done(function (){ 
        console.log("test");                        
    });
});
```

When I execute this code the functions are alright but the `console.log()` appears when the `function1` is finished, but I want to show only when `function2` finishes.

```
function function1() {
    $.ajax(
        {
        type: "GET",
        url: "<?=baseURL;?>/server/null/list_user_customers",
        async: true,
        success: function(data) {

            data = $.parseJSON(data);
                // Create a deferred object
            var dfd = $.Deferred();
            dfd;
        }
    });
}
function function2() {
    $.ajax(
        {
        type: "GET",
        var url = "<?=baseURL;?>/logbook/null/reload_tickets?customer_id=" + $("#customer_select option:selected").val();
        async: true,
        success: function(data) {

            data = $.parseJSON(data);
                // Create a deferred object
            var dfd = $.Deferred();
            dfd;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate your problem as well as include what `function1` and `function2` are doing ?

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi they load my page, function1 loads a listbox with my customers, and function2 loads a table

Comment: please find the time to review the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the complete parameter on function 2

```
      function2(){

            $.ajax({
                    url: '/Controller/Method',
                    type: 'GET',
                    complete: function () { 
                          console.log("test");
                    }
                });
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution will not work because both of your functions do not return anything (in other words they return `undefined`) so the `$.get` call is empty and useless. What you need to do is something like the following :

```
// your two functions return the promises they create
function function1() {
    return $.ajax({
        // config...
    });
}
function function2() {
    return $.ajax({
        // config...
    });
}

// your main code only needs to execute those functions
// and manipulate the promises they return
function1().done(function() { 
    function2().done(function() { 
        console.log("test");
    });
});
```